# javascript date issue with Android emulator

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, date, android-emulator

I am trying to display the date on android emulator browser. The current code works fine on my PC web browser but it does not work properly on Android emulator web browser. Here are my two functions which I am using for this purpose.

```
dayOfWeek('Sun Jan 08 2012 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)');
dayOfWeek = function (d) {
            var dayNames = new Array('SUN','MON','TUE','WED','THU','FRI','SAT');
            var day = toTimestamp(d);
            //alert(day);
            return dayNames[day.getDay()];
        }

        toTimestamp = function (strDate){
            return new Date(Date.parse(strDate));
        }
```

I am passing date in this format "Sun Jan 08 2012 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)" which you can see in the code above as well.

PROBLEM:
The problem is on Android emulator browser it displays "undefined" where ti should appear name of the day such as "MON, TUE, WED" etc.

### How can I solve this problem?

In the past I had the same problem then it was solved with following function. I got this function from somewhere on internet. But now it does not work here I do not know why.

```
function relative_time(date_str) {
if (!date_str) {return;}
date_str = $.trim(date_str);
date_str = date_str.replace(/\.\d\d\d+/,""); // remove the milliseconds
date_str = date_str.replace(/-/,"/").replace(/-/,"/"); //substitute - with /
date_str = date_str.replace(/T/," ").replace(/Z/," UTC"); //remove T and substitute Z with UTC
date_str = date_str.replace(/([\+\-]\d\d)\:?(\d\d)/," $1$2"); // +08:00 -> +0800
var parsed_date = new Date(date_str);
var relative_to = (arguments.length > 1) ? arguments[1] : new Date(); //defines relative to what ..default is now
var delta = parseInt((relative_to.getTime()-parsed_date)/1000);
delta=(delta<2)?2:delta;
var r = '';
if (delta < 60) {
r = delta + ' seconds ago';
} else if(delta < 120) {
r = 'a minute ago';
} else if(delta < (45*60)) {
r = (parseInt(delta / 60, 10)).toString() + ' minutes ago';
} else if(delta < (2*60*60)) {
r = 'an hour ago';
} else if(delta < (24*60*60)) {
r = '' + (parseInt(delta / 3600, 10)).toString() + ' hours ago';
} else if(delta < (48*60*60)) {
r = 'a day ago';
} else {
r = (parseInt(delta / 86400, 10)).toString() + ' days ago';
}
return 'about ' + r;
};
```

Comment: Have you tried it on a device?

Comment: No I do not have device. Should this code works on device? If yes then it should also work on emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be you are using the function before you define it.  This is why you are receiving the undefined error.  Try changing the order so that the function is evaluated last.

```
dayOfWeek = function (d) {
            var dayNames = new Array('SUN','MON','TUE','WED','THU','FRI','SAT');
            var day = toTimestamp(d);
            //alert(day);
            return dayNames[day.getDay()];
        }
toTimestamp = function (strDate){
            return new Date(Date.parse(strDate));
        }
dayOfWeek('Sun Jan 08 2012 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)');
```

Comment: I have no idea which line has the error. I guess it is the time format which makes the problem here.

Comment: @al0neevenings the `Date.parse` should be fine. I ran the entire code sample in Chrome and it's correct. This may be an issue in the emulator. Have you tried attaching a debugger and seeing where the error is?

Comment: Should I attach the debugger in emulator. I have the debugger in my firefox and chrome. It does not show any error over there.

Comment: @al0neevenings yes to the emulator. I verified it works fine with Chrome

Comment: I am trying to use ddms but when i run this says "Failed to parse the output of adb version".

Comment: @al0neevenings That's outside my experience of Android developement. If the debugger isn't working though i would start adding alerts in various places in order to search down the line which is actually causing the problem.  Big issue right now is it's hard to tell what's failing (since it should work)

Comment: The problem is with dayOfWeek function. Since when I use this line alert(dayNames[day.getDay()]); it shows my udefined.

Comment: Ok I found the line where the error occurs. The line is this var day = toTimestamp(d); in dayOfWeek function.

Comment: It means toTimestamp function has a problem. I have no Idea what is the problem with this function.

Comment: Sorry guys I made one mistake in my post. Here is what I am passing to dayOfWeek('2012-01-08') function. The date format in YYYY-MM-DD not in the post above.

Comment: SOLUTION. The date format which I was passing in dayOfWeek was in this format YYYY-MM-DD. So what I did is I first converted it to YYYY/MM/DD i.e. I replaced "-" with "/" and then I passed that date to toTimestamp method. Then it works perfectly fine. Thanks dude for trying helping me.